Positional encoding transition between consecutive elements of a sentence
I would like to interpret the result of a positional encoding with the values I see in order to understand the concept better. For a simple case where there are two words, w0 and w1 and vector dimension of 4, the result of positional encoding matrix is:
           0 (sin)    1 (cos)    2 (sin)     3 (cos)
        ----------------------------------------------
w0 -->      0.0        1.0        0.0         1.0
w1 -->      0.84       0.99       0.0         0.99

I want to understand the transition between 0 and near 1 for PE(0) while no transition for other PEs. What does that logically mean?
